# How do I remove a generated route created with angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

If I have generated a route I would like to remove, is it enough to delete the created directory, the route path placed and the entry in the system-config.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the current version of the CLI, you will also need to delete the definition of the route from the parent component as well.

Comment: I forgot the definition but here TypeScripts comes in handy.

Answer (score 6):

Answered on 31.01.2017 after the changes have seen-

Currently angular-cli is not supporting destroy commands `ng d component/whatever` doesn't work
Since it was a remnant from ember-cli functionality and doesn't remove the imports and component/whatever from the declarations array.

It throws an error **`The destroy command is not supported by Angular-CLI.`**

Answer (score 3):

You can Delete a component  from terminal by typing

```
ng d component "your_component"
```

May be same way you can delete your route

```
ng d route "your_route_name"
```

I didnt tried route deletion  yet but component deletion works for me, may be you can try :)

Comment: I had my route as a child route, so this didn't work, But thanks for the answer.

Comment: How did you create your child route ?

Comment: ng g route parent/child

Comment: Unfortunate no it uninstalled ´uninstalling route´
´uninstalling route-test´

Comment: This is the official way to remove a component, but unfortunately it misses the reference in src/system-config.ts

Comment: `ng d component` gave me an error `The destroy command is not supported by Angular-CLI.`

Comment: can you try ng delete component "your_component" and let me know again :)
Yes it not in their officical documentation,but it certainly works

Comment: The specified command delete is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.